# bind values to combobox through ViewModel in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I'm new to WPF and I just trying to bind list of values to a Combox using viewmodel class, since I'm trying to follow MVVM pattern here.

this is working properly,  except its not bind the first item as default item to combo box drop-down, though I setup `SelectedIndex="0"`

Here how I did this

this is the combo box XML

```
<ComboBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SAMPLE_NAME}"
            SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" DisplayMemberPath="SAMPLE_NAME" SelectedIndex="0" SelectedValuePath="SAMPLE_ID" />
```

this is **SampleModel** model class

```
public class SampleModel
{
    public int SAMPLE_ID { get; set; }
    public string SAMPLE_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

this is the ViewModel Class

```
public class SampleViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public SampleViewModel()
    {

    }
    private ObservableCollection<SampleModel> _samples;

    public ObservableCollection<SampleModel> Samples
    {
        get
        {
            return _samples;
        }
        set
        {
            _samples = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Samples");
        }
    }

    public void FillSamplesDropdown(string Id)
    {
        using (var _context = new SampleBL())
        {
            List<SampleModel> _samples = _context.GetAllSamples(Id);
            Samples = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>(_samples);
        }           

    }
}
```

This is the code behind file that exist combo box

```
public partial class SamplePopup : Window
{
    public SamplePopup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
        this.DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
    }

    private void ComboBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SampleViewModel ddl = (SampleViewModel)this.DataContext;
            ddl.FillSamplesDropdown(null);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SampleViewModel ddl= (SampleViewModel)this.DataContext;

            // ... Get the ComboBox.
            var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

            ...

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, SelectedIndex is fiddly as hell.  Always better to go with ItemsSource and SelectedItem.  Just make sure that the instance found in SelectedItem can be found in ItemSource, and things just work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with `SelectedIndex`, and get rid of the code in `ComboBox_Loaded`. Rename `FillSamplesDropdown()` to `FillSampleList()` or something that makes no reference to the user interface. The viewmodel shouldn't "know" that the UI exists. Then call `FillSampleList()` (or whatever you call it) in the viewmodel constructor.

Give your viewmodel a selected sample property:

```
public class SampleViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public SampleViewModel()
    {
    }

    private SampleModel _selectedSample;
    public SampleModel SelectedSample
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedSample;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedSample= value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedSample");
        }
    }
```

When you initialize `Samples`, set `SelectedSample` to the first item:

```
public void FillSamplesList(Object o)
{
    Samples = new ObservableCollection<Sample>();

    //  ...populate...

    SelectedSample = Samples.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Your view then binds `SelectedSample`. This illustrates what `SelectedItem` is for; what you did with it won't do anything, because your viewmodel has no `SAMPLE_NAME` property.

If you're not binding a `SelectedSampleID` property to `SelectedValue`, by the way, don't bother setting `SelectedValuePath`.

```
<ComboBox 
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Samples}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSample}"
    DisplayMemberPath="SAMPLE_NAME" 
    />
```